# Not Equal to Null condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, null, comparison

I am using this code on a button in Salesforce -- onClick JavaScript :

Is this is the correct way:

```
if('{!Account.CSS_CustomerID__c}' != 'null'){

          //do something
}
```

**Should I do like this --1**

```
 if('{!Account.CSS_CustomerID__c}' != null){

              //do something
    }
```

**Should I do like this --2**

```
 if('{!Account.CSS_CustomerID__c}' !== null){

              //do something
    }
```

Or there is any other way?

**ANSWER : This worked for me**

```
 if('{!Account.CSS_CustomerID__c}' !== null){

              //do something
    }
```

Comment: You are comparing `string` with `string` which is un-identical..

Comment: it is obvious that first string is not equal to second one, or you did not explain well..

Comment: I gone through the existing Question .... But I am not able to find out how to check for NOT EQUAL TO NULL CONDITION there

Answer (score 1):

With your code you compare two string.

Maybe you need to compare the variable :

```
if(!Account.CSS_CustomerID__c != null)
```

Comment: Can you give me the exact syntax for above if condition

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp